# Azure script validate insert item

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-mobile-services

I tried make server logic script. I don't know js, so I trying.
My table name is player.

```
id   Guid                               NamePlayer Score    
1   b91518c3-759d-45ef-9ee0-5d7584d96924    user    0   
2   e65661f5-88bf-467c-b850-290ec3f1e07d    empty   0
3   5636dde3-9ec3-47e4-92df-0295b16d4c70    empty   0
4   7e1e6c9b-adcc-4fbd-92d5-ac8fb0f75177    empty   0   
5   7b5f6e4b-696d-4aea-93e0-1cc6309046a5    empty   0   
6   40c80b1c-89f3-4628-bf11-eeb954902d33    emptydd 0   
7   c9024cbb-760b-49ce-917a-cc7d607e9290    empty   0   
8   36f553ce-1ab4-4b9c-b693-10df8f795e0a    emptymm 0
```

This is my logic.

```
   function insert(item, user, request) {
    var players = tables.getTable('player');
    for (var index = 0; index < players.length; index++) {
        if(players[index].NamePlayer===item.NamePlayer){
                console.log('One user have this name');
        }else {
            request.execute();

          }
       }
    }
```

How I have fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `table` object which you get back on the call to `tables.getTable('player')` is not an array with all items; instead it's an object on which you can query the database - for more information see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj554210.aspx.

What you need to do is to first query the objects in your table, and after that, in the callback (remember on the server side all calls to the database are asynchronous) respond accordingly, like in the code below:

```
function insert(item, user, request) {
    var playersTable = tables.getTable('player');
    playersTable.where({ NamePlayer: item.NamePlayer }).read({
        success: function(results) {
            if (results.length > 0) {
                request.respond(
                    statusCodes.BAD_REQUEST,
                    { error: 'A user already has this name' });
            } else {
                // Unique user, execute the insert
                request.execute();
            }
        }
    });
}
```